# How to get better photos with Canon's G12 built-in flash?

Tags: canon, flash, shooting-technique

My camera is a Canon G12. I don't have a fancy add-on flash.

My main problems are:

1. how can I get better images with the built-in flash in the Canon G12?
2. What techniques can I use to make the built-in flash a bigger light source so that the image is softer and better?

Comment: This camera does not have a popup flash. Its stuck on the front part of the camera always.

Comment: I don't think anything in the answers is really specific to that, though. Built-in flash either way.

Comment: just a side note, you don't have to put html break line tags when you format your question, simply hit the _return key_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that the main problem with built-in flashes is that they give a very harsh light.

Try making or buying a diffuser / deflecter. If you have some spare white plastic or translucent plastic, cut a piece and experiment with some blu-tac or tape.

http://photography-on-the.net/forum/showthread.php?t=949593